# I'm wondering how to get the ejs into the iframe src property

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```
<iframe class="iframe-preview" width="100%" src="./views/main.ejs"> 
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to call `index.ejs` from `node.js` and `main.ejs` from `index.ejs`. The `index.ejs` appear well on the screen, but the `main.ejs` continue to download...
Is there a way to display the `ejs` on the screen with `iframe`?

Comment: views resources are not public in nodejs server so you cant do that  instead you can include it using <%-

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using ejs in DOM while it is a server-side technology therefore ejs files are not and shouldn't be available in browser. Instead use it like this:

```
    <iframe class="iframe-preview" width="100%" src="/main"> 
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

where link to "/main" would open your router

```
router.get('/main',(req,res)=>{res.render('./views/main.ejs'})
```

and return your page wherever you want (in iframe if you wish).